# d3.js v5 Sankey Particle

Tags: d3.js

I've updated a Sankey Particle diagram to generate properly under d3.js v4 as shown in my [block](http://blockbuilder.org/glimpsedchaos/a495d51501fb6915db720042887e4430).

I am now trying to get it to generate properly under d3.js v5. The block builder does not display any errors.

I've looked through the release notes for v5 and found no changes that would cause it to fail.

Hoping someone has come across this or might know what the issue is.

Comment: d3.json changes from d3-request to d3-fetch when upgrading from v4 to v5. You want something like: `d3.json("file").then(function(data) { ... })` not `d3.json("file", function(data) {... })`. See: https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch

Comment: BAH! The adoption of using a promise. I moved right past that... sorry about that! Your answer is spot on, feel free to update it as an answer and I will check it off. Thanks much!